# Combining Rule Logic in Drools Expert

Tags: drools

In Drools, is it possible to combine rules in a DRL file somehow once they are defined. For example, if I have two rules like this:

```
rule A
 // definition
end

rule B
 // definition
end
```

Is it possible to have another rule that achieves logic like: A or B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two rules A and B *are* the logical equivalent of A or B (not xor).

You cannot refer to another rule, but you can define queries and call two (or more) queries within the same LHS condition.

However, the overall pattern of your logic might make an entirely different approach more advisable, where matches of different rules are made tangible by insertion as derived facts, known as truth maintenance.

```
rule A when ... then
  insertLogical( new Fired( "A" ) );
end
rule B when ... then
  insertLogical( new Fired( "B" ) );
end
rule AorB when
  Fired( rule == "A" || rule == "B" ) // other patterns for other combinations, e.g. &&
then
   ...
end
```

More details would be necessary for precise advice.

Comment: That works well for my situation. I am trying to model the state of a system. So I'll be able to capture, and notify Drools of the state of the system with the rules and then make inferences later.

Comment: I assume that the Fired class has the member rule which is initialized in the constructor. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at activation-group, which will fire one rule and cancel the others.